# Sending value into Channel and Reading output when Ready

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am trying to construct a receiver and sender pattern using two channels in Golang. I am doing a task (API call), and receiving back a `Response` struct. My goal is that when a response is received I'd like to send it to another channel (`writeChan`) for additional processing.

I'd like to continuously read/listen on that receiver channel (`respChan`) and process anything that comes through (such as a `Response`). Then I'd like to spin up a thread to go and do a further operation with that Response in another goroutine.

I'd like to understand how I can chain together this pattern to allow data to flow from the API calls and concurrently write it (each Response will be written to a separate file destination which the `Write()` func handles.

Essentially my current pattern is the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    respChan := make(chan Response) // Response is a struct that contains API response metadata
    defer close(respChan)
    // requests is just a slice of requests to be made to an API
    // This part is working well
    for _, req := range requests {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(r Request) {
            defer wg.Done()
            resp, _ := r.Get() // Make the API call and receive back a Response struct
            respChan <- resp // Put the response into our channel
        }(req)
    }

    // Now, I want to extract the responses as they become available and send them to another function to do some processing. This I am unsure of how to handle properly
    writeChan := make(chan string)
    defer close(writeChan)
    select {
        case resp := <-respChan: // receive from response channel
            go func(response Response) {
                signal, _ := Write(response) // Separate func to write the response to a file. Not important here in this context.
                writeChan <- signal // Put the signal data into the channel which is a string file path of where the file was written (will be used for a later process)

            }(resp)
        case <-time.After(15 *time.Second):
            fmt.Println("15 seconds have passed without receiving anything...")

    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me share with you a working example that you can benefit from. First, I'm gonna present the code, then, I'm gonna walk you through all the relevant sections.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type Request struct {
    Url            string
    DelayInSeconds time.Duration
}

type Response struct {
    Url        string
    StatusCode int
}

func main() {
    requests := []Request{
        {"https://www.google.com", 0},
        {"https://stackoverflow.com", 1},
        {"https://www.wikipedia.com", 4},
    }

    respChan := make(chan Response)
    defer close(respChan)

    for _, req := range requests {
        go func(r Request) {
            fmt.Printf("%q - %v\n", r.Url, strings.Repeat("#", 30))
            // simulate heavy work
            time.Sleep(time.Second * r.DelayInSeconds)
            resp, _ := http.Get(r.Url)
            res := Response{r.Url, resp.StatusCode}
            fmt.Println(time.Now())
            respChan <- res
        }(req)
    }

    writeChan := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(writeChan)

    for i := 0; i < len(requests); i++ {
        select {
        case res := <-respChan:
            go func(r Response) {
                f, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%v.txt", strings.Replace(r.Url, "https://", "", 1)))
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                defer f.Close()
                f.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%q OK with %d\n", r.Url, r.StatusCode)))
                writeChan <- struct{}{}
            }(res)
        case <-time.After(time.Second * 2):
            fmt.Println("Timeout")
        }
    }
}
```

#### Set up

First, I've defined the two structs that will be used in the example: `Request` and `Response`. In the former, I put a `DelayInSeconds` to mock some heavy loads and time-consuming operations. Then, I defined the `requests` variable that contains all the requests that have to be done.

#### The writing part

Here, I range over the `requests` variable. For each request, I'm gonna issue an HTTP request to the target URL. The `time.Sleep` emulate the heavy load. Then, I write the response to the `respChan` channel which is unbuffered.

#### The reading part

Here, the major change is to wrap the `select` construct into a `for` loop. Thanks to this, we'll make sure to iterate the right times (based on the length of the `requests` variable).

#### Final notes

First of all, bear in mind that the code is oversimplified just to show off the relevant parts. Due to this, a lot of error handling is missing and some inline functions could be extrapolated into named functions. You don't need to use `sync.WaitGroup` to achieve what you need, the usage of channels will be enough.
*Feel free to play with delays and check which files are written!*

Let me know if this helps you!

### Edit

As requested, I'm gonna provide you with a more accurate solution based on your needs. The new reading part will be something like the following:

```golang
count := 0
for {
    // this check is need to exit the for loop and not wait indefinitely
    // it can be removed based on your needs
    if count == 3 {
        fmt.Println("all responses arrived...")
        return
    }
    res := <-respChan
    count++
    go func(r Response) {
        f, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%v.txt", strings.Replace(r.Url, "https://", "", 1)))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer f.Close()
        f.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%q OK with %d\n", r.Url, r.StatusCode)))
        writeChan <- struct{}{}
    }(res)
}
```

Here, the execution is waiting indefinitely within the `for` loop. No matter how long each request takes to complete, it will be fetched as soon as it arrives. I put, at the top of the `for` loop, an `if` to exit after it processed the requests that we need. However, you can avoid it and let the code run till a cancellation signal comes in (it's up to you).

Let me know if this better meets your requirements, thanks!

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you. I will be assessing this in practice, but wanted to inquire. This will run asynchronously, correct? I guess mentally I'm imagining the for loop would just iterate and if it didn't have a response it would do nothing. What if the server takes a few seconds to respond? Is it imperative that I set a large timeout (```time.After```)? Ideally, I'd just like the 2nd channel to wait infinitely until a request is received and then send it to the ```Write``` func.

Comment: My ultimate goal is for the 2nd channel to "listen" for responses from the first, and allocate a thread to handle a response as it arrives, without any blocking whatsoever.

Comment: Man, I just updated the answer with the relevant changes to apply to my previous answer, let me know!

Comment: This totally makes sense. Thank you for your excellent answer!

Comment: So I've put this into practice and its working really well. The only issue I currently have is with gracefully terminating the loop. Currently, if the response isn't ready in the infinite loop, it will still increment the counter, and then after the counter matches my terminate  condition (say counter == len(requests)) then it will exit early. I basically need to find a way to make sure it only increments if an item was successfully pulled from the channel to be written to file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for your response channel to wait for the responses from the api>

```
 You can use this pattern>
 for _, value := range respChan {
  // spin a goroutine here
 }
```

the above code waits for the response.